# error when using Kotlin groupBy function applied to list

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, group-by

I'm very new in Kotlin, and I can't seem to figure out how to do something that is really quite simple; grouping my data by the name field. I've tried with map and groupBy, using one or using both, but I either get an error, or the data is  in a list, and the duplicates are filtered out - which I don't want. I need the duplicates grouped.

As an aside, my sql function (in the repository), which finds records in my DB based on the date entered has fields from two different classes, which isn't the optimal way of doing things, but I didn't know how else to combine the data from two tables. I don't mind correcting that if someone can tell me how. The error that I get is "Type inference failed. Expected Type mismatch. Required: List Found Map 
String?, List>

below is my code

TIA

my repository code

```
    @Query("SELECT new XXX.report.model.ReportWithBatches(r.adlsPath, r.fileSize, r.lastUpdate, r.remoteFileName, b.dataPath , b.version, b.dataSource, r.recordCount, r.transferStatus, r.businessDate) FROM ReportOutput r INNER JOIN BatchInput b ON r.job.jobUuid = b.reportJob.jobUuid WHERE r.businessDate = ?1")
    fun findAllByBusinessDateJoinBatches(date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches>


}
```

my service code

```
 fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches> {
            val reportBatchesList = reportRepository.findAllByBusinessDateJoinBatches(date)
           return reportBatchesList.groupBy({it.adlsFullPath}, {it})
//                   .map { it.value }
//            return reportBatchesList
//            return reportBatchesList.map { rB ->
//                ReportWithBatches(
//                        rB.adlsFullPath,
//                        rB.contentLength,
//                        rB.lastModified,
//                        rB.remoteFileName,
//                        rB.dataPath,
//                        rB.version,
//                        rB.source,
//                        rB.numberOfRecords,
//                        rB.transferStatus,
//                        rB.creationDate)
//
//            }

        }
```

code in my controller

```
 @GetMapping(value = ["/linkBatches/{today}"])
    fun findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(@PathVariable("today") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyyMMdd") date: LocalDate): List<ReportWithBatches> {
        return eligibleService.findAllByCreationDateJoinBatches(date)
    }
```

My result is this - note there's only one batch per record in the result:

```
[
  {
    "adlsFullPath": "part-00000-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
    "contentLength": 20,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.132-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07"
  },
  {
    "adlsFullPath": "part-00007-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
    "contentLength": 1104,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.133-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "dataPath": "preprd/datalake/lake/nes/negotiation/execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07"
  },
  {
    "adlsFullPath": "part-00015-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
    "contentLength": 1057,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.133-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "dataPath": "preprd/datalake/lake/nes/negotiation/execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07"
  },
]
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
[{
    "adlsFullPath": "part-00000-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
    "contentLength": 20,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.132-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07",
    "batches":{  
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=2/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=1/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    }
  },

  { 
    "adlsFullPath": "part-00007-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
    "contentLength": 1104,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.133-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07",
    "batches":{  
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=2/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=1/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    }
  },

  {
    "part-00015-1399b2e0-5fa5-484b-91f1-9dec0601b885-c000.csv.gz",
   "contentLength": 1104,
    "lastModified": "2020-02-07T16:50:16.133-05:00",
    "remoteFileName": null,
    "numberOfRecords": -1,
    "transferStatus": "REPORT_CREATED",
    "creationDate": "2020-02-07",
    "batches":{  
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=3/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=2/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    },
    {  "dataPath": "execution_v1/integration_date=2020-02-07/business_date=2020-02-07/batch_id=1/version=1",
    "version": 1,
    "source": "NETS",
    }
  }
  }]
```

Comment: Since this isn't to do with the DB, could you create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can run and test with?  It'd also help if you could show what the results are, and what you'd like them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `groupBy` returns a `Map` not a `List`, you get an error when you do

```
return reportBatchesList.groupBy({it.adlsFullPath}, {it})
```

From a `function` having `return` type `List<ReportWithBatches>`. So you will have to change the return type of your `function` to `Map<String, ReportWithBatches>` in service.

In your case `groupBy` will give you a Map which will look something as following

```
{adlsFullPath1=[Report1, Report2], adlsFullPath2=[Report3]}
```

For more information read the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html).

Comment: I've looked at the docs but I'm still not getting it. When you say to "change the return type" that is my problem. I'm not sure what to change it to. If I change it to Map<ReportBatches>, it asks for two arguments, key and value; I'm not sure what I need to put. or is there something else I should change it to? I need my data to be grouped by my fields in the class ReportBatches.

Comment: You should change it to Map<TypeOfAdlsFullPath,ReportWithBatches>.

Comment: It seems TypeOfAdlsFullPath is String. So groupBy will return Map<String, ReportBatches>

Comment: I did Map<String?, List<ReportBatches> and it worked. thanks.